# Where should "help with my Git workflow" questions go

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

A lot of the questions posted to [git](/questions/tagged/git) on Stack Overflow are along the lines of "I'm doing this and that, how should I manage ...". I'm under the impression that questions about concepts and ideas would go to [Programmers SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com), and issues with implementation would go to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Should questions like this...

> "I'm doing *[something]* and I use Git *[or another version control system]* and I want do *[something else]*, how should I manage my repository"

... be closed as too localized or migrated to [Programmers SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com). What should be done with these sorts of questions?

Comment: (Not constructive rather than too localised?)

Comment: I think we first need to figure out if questions about workflows are on-topic on SO. As said by @hayden, they most of the time qualify as Not Constructive.

Comment: I think that questions about Git implementation (ie. "this command didn't work" etc.) are on topic with SO. "Help me figure out a workflow" questions are either on-topic with Programmers (I think) and not-constructive on SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In broad terms, if your question is about your workflow (e.g. your branching strategy), feel free to ask it on Programmers. If, on the other hand, your question is about git the tool (e.g. setting it up, using its command line interface, etc), then Stack Overflow would be the more suitable site.

However, the lines aren't always clear. If a question fits on both sites, then the easiest solution is to leave it where it was originally asked. Keep in mind that a migration starts with an off topic vote, if a question is not 100% off topic on the site it was asked, then there's little reason to send it elsewhere. Especially if it has already been answered.